# Deprecation warnings when using internal Keras library in Tensorflow 1.15.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am upgrading our codebase to Tensorflow 1.15.0 (we plan to eventually upgrade to 2.x, but it requires too many changes at the moment). Unfortunately, this version of Tensorflow seems to be plagued by deprecation warnings related to the internal Keras library.

Example with Tensorflow 1.15.0:

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, May  2 2019, 19:44:18)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.15.0'
>>> from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
>>> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(Dense(units=100, input_shape=(100,)))
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W1111 10:20:25.954580 140456260341888 deprecation.py:506] From /home/user/.python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
```

Same code with Tensorflow 2.0 (i.e. expected result, without warnings):

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, May  2 2019, 19:44:18)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>> from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
>>> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(Dense(units=100, input_shape=(100,)))
2019-11-11 10:21:28.767760: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-11 10:21:28.778339: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2712000000 Hz
2019-11-11 10:21:28.781231: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fffe1268cc0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-11 10:21:28.782216: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

Any advice on how to avoid these warnings?

Comment: If the warnings really annoy you (note they just pop up once per function), I think the best you can do is [silence them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626757/1782792).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to remove them since the Tensorflow/Keras code is part of a service: warnings would trigger various alerts. I'm aware I can silence them, but it's not ideal: once silenced, we might miss warnings related to actual problems. I'm amazed at how 1.15 was released with these warnings. We are not talking about Tensorflow deprecating some behavior and we start to get deprecation warnings from external libraries, and we have to wait for them to get updated: these warnings are triggered by the internal `tf.keras` library, which is also nowadays the reference high-level API.

Comment: Yes, I know, I have experienced the issue myself. Unfortunately the warnings are in the code, and I don't think there is a way to filter them specifically (besides disabling and re-enabling the warnings selectively). I _think_ the last version without them was 1.13.2. Not that it is very useful but the warnings do seem to go away if you use TF2 mode with `tf.enable_v2_behavior()` or with the [`TF2_BEHAVIOR` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625794/1782792).

Comment: yeah, apparently the problem is limited to the 1.x API... I guess the Tensorflow team bothered to fix the warnings only for the 2.x API. So, it seems like the only solutions are either to disable warnings entirely until the code can be migrated to the 2.x API, or migrate directly. I still hope there might be a third solution :)

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like the same warnings appear even with the 2.x API (and even in Tensorflow 2.0.0), just at a later stage. Namely, they appear when the model is saved to disk (with either `model.save(path)` or `tf.saved_model.save(model, path)`). I guess the warnings get triggered when the graph is built (in 1.x immediately, in 2.x when the model is saved). The only solution appears then to disable warnings entirely until Tensorflow gets its shit together, but I hope for a better suggestion!